# Bot not sending Canvas - discord.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm doing a testing bot in discord.js that sends profile cards when the $profile command is called.
But i have zero experience with Canvas so I googled some tutorials and followed them

But the problem is that the bot doesn't send the attachment, I've tried to research other ways to do that but they don't work either

This is the code of the canvas

```js
const Canvas = require('canvas')
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports =
{
    name: 'profile',
    description: '',
    run: async (client, message) =>
        {
            const profilecanvas = Canvas.createCanvas(660,315)
            const ctx = profilecanvas.getContext('2d')
            const bg = await Canvas.loadImage('https://i.imgur.com/______.png')

            ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, profilecanvas.width, profilecanvas.height);
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#fdfd34';
            ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, profilecanvas.width, profilecanvas.height);

            const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(profilecanvas.toBuffer(), bg);

            message.channel.send('testing', attachment)
        }
    }
```

And it sends the "testing" normally, only the Canvas is not sent and no syntax error appears in the terminal

Comment: What version of the Discord.js package do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a [MessageOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions) type  parameter, with an `attachments` property whose value is an array with your `attachment` as its only element, and a `content` property of value "testing":

```js
message.channel.send({
    attachments: [attachment],
    content: "testing",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```js
message.channel.send({files: [attachment]});
```

and if you want to have a picture and text in one message then

```js
        message.channel.send({
            files: [attachment],
            content: 'Message text'
        });
```